# Acumatica REST API get field from customization

Tags: rest, acumatica

I have added some informational field to PM Project by the following code:

```
public class ContractExt:PXCacheExtension<Contract>
{
    #region SomeContractID
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Some Contract ID")]
    [PXDBString(9,IsUnicode = true)]
    public string SomeContractID{ get; set; }
    public abstract class someContractID: IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```

Now I am trying to get the Project by REST API in the following way:

```
var res = _httpClient.GetAsync(_acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/" + _endpoint + "/" + _version + "/" + "My_Project"+ "?" + "$custom=Project.SomeContractID&top=1").Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
return res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

But everytime I'm getting the result with empty field like this:

> "[{\"id\":\"c38bb35a-f609-4e65-998a-0e9e60063573\" \"rowNumber\":1
>   \"note\":\"\" \"AllocationRule\":{\"value\":\"ALLOCATION\"}
>   \"BillingRule\":{\"value\":\"BILLINGRULE\"}
>   \"Customer\":{\"value\":\"GOTO\"}
>   \"Description\":{\"value\":\"GOTO Acumatica Project\"}
>   \"EndDate\":{}
>   \"ProjectID\":{\"value\":\"PR00000001\"}
>   \"RateTable\":{\"value\":\"STD 175\"}
>   \"SomeContractID\":{}
>   \"StartDate\":{\"value\":\"2015-09-14T00:00:00+04:00\"}
>   \"Status\":{\"value\":\"Active\"}
>   \"custom\":{\"Project\":{\"SomeContractID\": \"type\":\"String\",\"value\":null}}}
>   \"files\":[]}]"

But this project's that field has value and it's not null.
I have tried to get this field's value by Screen Based SOAP API also.
The result is the same.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: After some experiments it has come out that when request is for specific Project with Project ID the custom field is being returned with it's data, but if request is for some dataset the custom field is returned with null value.

Comment: can you show us where the custom field is located?

Comment: Since the project Screen is not part of the default endpoint, is there a reason you are not adding this field to your custom endpoint?

Comment: @samol518 that field is added to custom endpoint like the whole project

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the endpoint definition as normally if you add a field in the field list you should not have to specify it in the custom tag.
The custom tag is only to use when you want to see a field no in the endpoint definition but not so much that you would customize or add it to the endpoint.

Comment: @samol518 I can't add screenshot as there is internal information of the company. The field is added to the endpoint. I have tried to get the data both with and without specifying the field as custom.